# Search through an array and save its parent and child elements in new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, tree

I have one array with id, skill and parent properties in it. I want to search an element within that array. If found, I am saving it in a new array. Then I want to search its parent, and if the parent also has a parent, then save them too. I also want to save the children of the searched element if any and sibling should be added in the new array. Elements found to have no parent will stop the searches for further parent elements.

```js
var search = 'cde';

var data = [{
  'id': '99',
  'skill': 'pro',
  'parent': null
}, {
  'id': '0',
  'skill': 'abc',
  'parent': '99'
}, {
  'id': '1',
  'skill': 'bcd',
  'parent': null
}, {
  'id': '2',
  'skill': 'cde',
  'parent': '0'
}, {
  'id': '3',
  'skill': 'def',
  'parent': '0'
}, {
  'id': '4',
  'skill': 'efg',
  'parent': '1'
}, {
  'id': '5',
  'skill': 'fgh',
  'parent': '1'
}, {
  'id': '6',
  'skill': 'ghi',
  'parent': '2'
}, {
  'id': '7',
  'skill': 'hij',
  'parent': null
}];
var arrayP = [];

searchKey(search);

function searchKey(s) {
  var tmpskill = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].skill == s) {
      arrayP.push(data[i]);
      findParent(data[i].parent)
    } else {}
  }
}

function findParent(pid) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].id == pid) {
      arrayP.push(data[i]);
      if (data[i].parent != null) {
        findParent(data[i].parent);
      } else {}
    }
  }
}
console.log(arrayP);

function findChilds() {}
```

I have also created this as a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prashant_devs/qcv7dx8p/2/) (please look at the console for the output).

I have managed to add the parent elements in the new array but got stuck in adding the children and its siblings.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
function findChilds(id){
    return data.filter(v=>v.parent==id;);
}

function findSiblings(id){
    return data.filter(v=>v.parent==id.parent;);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.